# The particular word or phrase for description

Tags: single-word-requests

Detailed descriptions are used in poetry and prose[fiction or even non-fiction] to paint a vivid, detailed picture in the minds of the readers.
Authors achieve this feat using vivid imagery about a person or scenery or the emotional height of a particular situation.
What is the word or phrase used to describe this detailed description? I first thought of 'narration', but it didn't seem suitable. 
Thank You.

Comment: See also depict.

Comment: The adjective *evocative* will feel satisfying to include.  Evocative description.  Evocative imagery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You guessed it - **it's called imagery** in a professional environment, but conversationally you would just say something along the lines of 'detailed description' or 'vivid detail'.

Comment: Thank You Annie Levi, Imagery seems the right word as a literary device. But I think there should be some other word too, which describes the flow of words to bring forth an object or emotion in front of the reader.

Comment: Could it also be 'pathos' (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathos) where viewers/readers are swayed by emotion?

Comment: Pathos is the root word for 'pathetic'. So the word, though by general meaning emotion generator, in usage it marks only pity and sorrow.